# jquery binding data to multiple rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have coded the below to bind autocomplete data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title> Add row demo</title>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
  var availableTags = [
  "A 1 Object ", "A 2 Object ", "B Object ", "C Object ", "D Object ", "E Object ", "F Object ", "G Object ", "H Object ", "I Object "
  ];

function split( val ){
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}

$( "#tags" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  }).autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function( request, response ) {
      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
   },
    focus: function() {
     // prevent value inserted on focus
      return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      var terms = split( this.value );
      // remove the current input
      terms.pop();
      // add the selected item
      terms.push( ui.item.value );
      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
      terms.push( "" );
      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
      return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>


<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(function(){
$("#insert-more").click(function () {
 $("#mytable").each(function () {
     var tds = '<tr>';
     jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
         tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
     });
     tds += '</tr>';
     if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
         $('tbody', this).append(tds);
     } else {
         $(this).append(tds);
     }
 });
});

});
```

```
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a>

<br>
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Object</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="code">
                <option value="1">Item1</option>
                <option value="2">Item2</option>
                <option value="2">Item3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input id="tags" size="50">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But it `enter code here`works only for first row. 
Remaining rows dont work. 
Please help. 
Not sure how to bind data to multiple rows repetetive.
Any help will be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you get an error message? What is the desired output, what is the actual output? Help the people help you. And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I expect autocomplete to populate suggestible values in a drop down for each row added. It works for the first one only but for successive rows does not work. No error messages at all, its only about if it happens to one row applying it to remainder of the row is a question

Answer (score 0):

You are using `id="tags"` and this will not work for multiple elements as id should be unique.
Assign `class="tags"` to all input inside `tr`

```
<input class="tags" size="50">
```

And change your jquery to

```
$(".tags").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {...
```

**Edit** - Above solution work for static rows but not for dynamically added rows in table. Below is the solution for this problem -

You need to seperate autocomplete function and call it on input with `class="tags"`. Change the logic to create new row as shown in code and add autocomplete function to it.

jQuery :

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "A 1 Object ", "A 2 Object ", "B Object ", "C Object ", "D Object ", "E Object ", "F Object ", "G Object ", "H Object ", "I Object "];
    function split( val ){
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}
   //seperate autocomplete function
    autcomplet_func = {
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
        },
        focus: function () {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    };

 $(".tags").bind("keydown",function (event) {
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).autocomplete("instance").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    }).autocomplete(autcomplet_func);


    $("#insert-more").click(function () {
        var lastRow = $('#mytable tr:last').clone();
        $(lastRow).find('input').val('');
        // add autocomplete function here for new row
         $('.tags', lastRow).autocomplete(autcomplet_func);
        $('#mytable').append(lastRow);
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/a3qukdhn/31/)**

Comment: It makes sense and Tried using it but does not work. Can you kindly re-look your suggestion and see if it works. Incase if it does can you please paste the code here.

Comment: can you please share jsfiddle link with your current code, I will try with above code in it.

Comment: Thanks for taking concern. Currently fiddle seems to be down. Let me create it when it comes online, meanwhile the above can be directly saved as html and can be used.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/a3qukdhn/2/) is working as expected but not working for newly added rows. I am looking into it and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for creating the fiddle and looking into. Used console statements but couldn't trap where this is getting missed.

Comment: Please check the updated answer and let me know if any problem.